# Attaching a PDF to an email is not showing correctly

Tags: php, sql, database, email, pdf

We have an online test that once completed, we can email to the user. However, the data isn't being attached as a PDF, it's showing up in the email as a bunch of random letters/numbers.

Any advice on what is causing this? It was working up until a few months ago.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

$i_get_sid = isset($_GET["sid"]) ? (int)$_GET["sid"] : $i_sid;
$i_get_pass = isset($_GET["a"]) ? $_GET["a"] : $_SESSION['r_pass'];
$i_get_pass = addslashes($i_get_pass);

$i_qry1 = db_qry("SELECT * FROM reports WHERE sid={$i_get_sid} AND ispurchased=1 AND isenabled=1 AND passhash='$i_get_pass'")
 or die("Error: report-4, SQL request error #1 ".mysql_error());
if($i_qry1) {
    if($i_rec1=mysql_fetch_array($i_qry1)) {
        $i_fname = $i_rec1["fname"];
        $i_lname = $i_rec1["lname"];
        $i_email = $i_rec1["email"];
    }
    db_free_result($i_qry1);
}

if(!empty($i_email)) {
    ob_start();
    include('inc/pages/report-3.inc.php');
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $data = wordwrap(base64_encode($data), 72, "\n", true);
    $i_boundary = '----------'.bin2hex(mhash(MHASH_MD5, time()));
    $i_headers = "From: oursite.com <info@oursite.com>
X-Mailer: oursite.com PHP Mail (v1.0)
Reply-To: oursite.com <info@oursite.com>
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary=\"$i_boundary\"";
    $i_message = "--$i_boundary
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Dear ".$i_fname." ".$i_lname.",

Here is the report you asked for, attached as an Adobe Acrobat document.

If you do not already have one, an Adobe Acrobat reader can be downloaded
for free at http://www.adobe.com/.

----
Best regards,
OurSite Team
mailto:info@oursite.com

--$i_boundary
Content-Type: APPLICATION/PDF; name=\"report.pdf\"
Content-transfer-encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"report.pdf\"

$data

{$i_boundary}--
";

    @mail($i_email, 'Our Site - Your Report', $i_message, $i_headers);
    @mail('null@sight2k.com', 'Our Site - Your Report', "ID - $i_get_sid", $i_headers);
}

header('Content-type: text/html');
$m_header = '<link href="shared/report.css" rel=stylesheet type="text/css">';
require_once($DOCUMENT_ROOT."inc/top-2.inc.php");
$i_get_sid = isset($_GET["sid"]) ? (int)$_GET["sid"] : $i_sid;

$i_get_pass = isset($_GET["a"]) ? $_GET["a"] : $_SESSION['r_pass'];
$i_get_pass = addslashes($i_get_pass);

echo '<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width="100%">';
echo '<tr vAlign=top><td height=7><img src="images/1x1.gif" width=1 height=7></td></tr>';
echo '<tr height=28 style="background: url(images/bookm-bg.gif) repeat-x"><td width="100%"><nobr>';
echo '<img src="images/1x1.gif" width=5 height=1><a href="report.php?sid='.$i_get_sid.'&a='.urlencode($i_get_pass).'"><img src="images/bookm-42.gif" width=67 height=28 border=0></a><a href="report.php?sid='.$i_get_sid.'&a='.urlencode($i_get_pass).'&b=pdf"><img src="images/bookm-s3.gif" width=10 height=28 border=0><img src="images/bookm-52.gif" width=65 height=28 border=0></a>&nbsp;<a href="report.php?sid='.$i_get_sid.'&a='.urlencode($i_get_pass).'&b=/report.pdf"><img src="images/button-downloadpdf.gif" width=80 height=28 border=0></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="report.php?sid='.$i_get_sid.'&a='.urlencode($i_get_pass).'&b=email"><img src="images/button-emailpdf.gif" width=80 height=28 border=0></a>';
echo '</nobr></td><td><nobr><font style="font-size: 10px;"><a href="javascript:window.close();">Close Window</a>&nbsp;</font></nobr></td></tr></table>';
echo "<p>&nbsp;Thank you.";
echo "<p>&nbsp;Your report has been successfully sent.";
require_once($DOCUMENT_ROOT."inc/btm-2.inc.php");

// header("location: report.php?sid=$i_get_sid&a=".urlencode($i_get_pass));

?>
```

Here's an example of what arrives in the user's email (the random text goes on for a long time so I just pasted a few lines):

```
Dear "user",

Here is the report you asked for, attached as an Adobe Acrobat document.

If you do not already have one, an Adobe Acrobat reader can be downloaded
for free at http://www.adobe.com/.

----
Best regards,
Our Site
mailto:info@oursite.com

------------2040d59fa64b69be819a8c22f7d6c114
Content-Type: APPLICATION/PDF; name="report.pdf"
Content-transfer-encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="report.pdf"

JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL1Jlc291cmNl
cyAyIDAgUgovQ29udGVudHMgNCAwIFI+PgplbmRvYmoKNCAwIG9iago8PC9GaWx0ZXIgL0Zs
YXRlRGVjb2RlIC9MZW5ndGggMzE1Pj4Kc3RyZWFtCnicdVLLTsMwELznK+YIUnHtXTuxb0BL
```

Comment: Oh man... may I suggest PHPMailer? https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is wrong:

```
boundary=\"$i_boundary\"";
```

From the looks of your code, this should be:

```
boundary=\"--$i_boundary\"";
```

Secondly, I would suggest [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) - it is so much easier!

Comment: Thanks for the reply - that didn't fix it so I'll definitely look into phpmailer -- I inherited this code and it certainly hasn't been updated in forever =)